# Cargar itemsource a Oxyplot

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

tengo un problema con oxyplot en xamarin forms. Quiero cargar el item source de una lista

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<Registro> Registrar { get; } = new ObservableRangeCollection<Registro>();
```

En el ejemplo de Oxyplot de barseries usan:

```
 ItemsSource = new List<BarItem>(new[]
        {
                new BarItem{ Value = (cakePopularity[0] / sum * 100) },
                new BarItem{ Value = (cakePopularity[1] / sum * 100) },
                new BarItem{ Value = (cakePopularity[2] / sum * 100) },
                new BarItem{ Value = (cakePopularity[3] / sum * 100) },
                new BarItem{ Value = (cakePopularity[4] / sum * 100) }
        }),
```

Yo quiero agregar un item por cada valor de ancho en registro:

```
public class Registro
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Version]
        public string AzureVersion { get; set; }


        public string Recurso { get; set; }


        public string Orden { get; set; }


        public string Familia { get; set; }


        public string Genero { get; set; }


        public string Especie { get; set; }


        public double Largo { get; set; }


        public double Ancho { get; set; }


        public double Peso { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateUtc { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        public string DateDisplay { get { return DateUtc.ToLocalTime().ToString("d"); } }

    }
```

Pense en algo como esto:

```
ItemsSource = new List<BarItem>(new[]
        {
                new BarItem{ Value =  Registrar.OrderBy(c => c.Especie).Select(x => x.Ancho)},

                 }),
```

Pero el argumento del error es que:

> No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' en 'double'

Alguna sugerencia?
De antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: Si asi es el itemsource almacena 5 elementos estaticos, yo quiero generar items del itemsource desde una coleccionde registro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analicemos tu código:

```
ItemsSource = new List<BarItem>(new[]
    {new BarItem{ Value =  Registrar.OrderBy(c => c.Especie).Select(x => x.Ancho)}})
```

Estás intentado asignar a un valor de tipo `double` (`Value`) un `IEnumerable`, que es el resultado de tu consulta `Registrar.OrderBy(c => c.Especie).Select(x => x.Ancho)`. Obviamente esto no es posible.

Podríamos solucionarlo añadiendo `First()` a dicha consulta:

```
Registrar.OrderBy(c => c.Especie).Select(x => x.Ancho).First()
```

Pero obviamente esto no es lo que quieres, ya que lo único que haría sería crear una lista con un único `BarItem`, y entiendo que lo que quieres es añadir en una sola fila todos los `BarItems` con los valores que existen en `Registrar`.

Para conseguir eso habría varias formas, yo te propongo una:

```
ItemsSource = Registrar.OrderBy(c => c.Especie).Select(x=> new BarItem() { Value = x.Ancho }).ToList<BarItem>();
```

Primero ordenamos los datos de Registrar, y luego hacemos un `Select` que genera un nuevo `BarItem` con el valor `Ancho` de cada uno de los datos. Por último, devolvemos una `List` de tipo `BarItem`.

Es posible que haya que ajustar algo en mi solución ya que no la he probado, pero creo que podrás hacerte una idea de como resolverlo asi.

Comment: ok muchas gracias por responder. Pasa lo siguiente ahora al analizar con un alto el codigo en model.Series.Add(barSeries); barSeries si muestra esos valores en itemsource, pero items esta vacio, dejame probar el codigo que da oxyplot

Comment: Funciono!!  muchas gracias ya llevaba un rato con este problema

Comment: @Arima de nada, me alegro que te sirva :)